# JavaScript - Canvas: Why color of the last arrow is changing all arrows and the semicircle?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The below code creates 3 oval circles connected by arrows. Why the color of the last arrow is changing the first arrow and the semicircle of the third shape?

The first arrow should be black, anf the third shape should be full grey.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>

function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy, color) {
    context.lineWidth = 2; 
    context.strokeStyle = color;   
    var headlen = 10;   
    var angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));    
    context.stroke(); 
}

function canvas_shape(context, rowIDX, colIDX, boxWidth, boxHeight, sizeTextFont) {
    var box_shift = boxWidth + space; //boxWidth + arrowLength
    var box_shift_vert = boxHeight + space; //boxWidth + arrowLength

    var r = boxHeight / 3;//radius
    var l = boxWidth - 2*r; //line lentght
    var x = box_shift * (colIDX - 1) + r;
    var y = box_shift_vert * (rowIDX - 1) + r * 1.5;

    context.beginPath();        
    context.arc(x, y, r, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5, false); 
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = "grey";
    context.fill();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x + l, y, r, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5, true); 
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = "grey";
    context.fill();

    //BOX
    context.fillStyle = "grey";
    context.fillRect(x, y - r, l, 2*r); 
    context.fill();

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");
var arrowContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

var boxWidth=120;
var boxHeight=60;
var sizeTextFont=20;
var space=40;

canvas_shape(draw, 1, 1, boxWidth, boxHeight, sizeTextFont);
canvas_shape(draw, 1, 2, boxWidth, boxHeight, sizeTextFont);
canvas_shape(draw, 1, 3, boxWidth, boxHeight, sizeTextFont);

//Arrow 1-2
 var rowIDXfrom=1, colIDXfrom=1;
 var rowIDXto=1, colIDXto=2;
 var fromx = (colIDXfrom) * (boxWidth) + (colIDXfrom - 1) * (space);
 var fromy = (rowIDXfrom - 1) * (boxHeight + space) + (boxHeight / 2); 
 var tox = (colIDXto - 1) * (boxWidth + space);
 var toy = (rowIDXto - 1) * (boxHeight + space) + (boxHeight / 2);
 canvas_arrow(draw, fromx, fromy, tox, toy, "black");

//Arrow 2-3
 var rowIDXfrom=1, colIDXfrom=2;
 var rowIDXto=1, colIDXto=3;
 var fromx = (colIDXfrom) * (boxWidth) + (colIDXfrom - 1) * (space);
 var fromy = (rowIDXfrom - 1) * (boxHeight + space) + (boxHeight / 2); 
 var tox = (colIDXto - 1) * (boxWidth + space);
 var toy = (rowIDXto - 1) * (boxHeight + space) + (boxHeight / 2);
 canvas_arrow(draw, fromx, fromy, tox, toy, "red");

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me here? Many thanks in advance.
While posting the question, the stackoverflow is showing an error saying "It looks like your question is mostly code" but I think it is clear enough...

Comment: Add `context.beginPath()` to the `canvas_arrow` function before the first `moveTo`

Comment: That is it! Thanks!